# How to Add Fields (Columns) in a QueryDef Using Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm trying to add a new field in a querydef with the Fields.Append method. Firstly, I tryed the follownig code:

```
Dim myField as Field    
myQueryDef.Fields.Append myField
```

Then, I tryed as follows:

```
myQueryDef.Fields.Append "my_field_name"
```

None of then worked. Maybe, something is missing. maybe not. If any of you know how to do it, please, help me. I'd appreciate your help.

I also need to add this new field in a especific position within the querydef, the second position.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you are not confusing tabledef and querydef? A querydef uses an sql statement, a tabledef allows you to add fields / columns but the position is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you can add a field to a `QueryDef` object is by changing the SQL statement in the `.SQL` property to output an additional column. Yes, the `QueryDef` object has a `.Fields` property, but it is read-only (ref: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb257297%28v=office.12%29.aspx)).

Comment: really? I thought it was possible. what a pity! well, what about inserting the new column in the second position within the querydef/tabledef using the SQL statement? thanks a lot, Gord.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this (see Gords Answer) is:

```
dim SQLstring as string
SQLString=myQueryDef.SQL
myQueryDef.SQL=Replace(SQLString,"FROM",", myField FROM")
```

Comment: ok. I understood, Johanness. so, if I want to insert myField right after the first field with the SQL statement, I should replace the source SQL like as follows: myQueryDef.SQL=Replace(SQLString,"firstField","firstField, myField") I thought there was a more automated way. thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: QueryDefs are just stored procedures (=very simple objects). Unlike Tables where you have to be able to change one field without affecting the other, you actually replace the one procedure (=SQL String) with another (=new SQL String).